# Display items from MongoDB to FrontEnd

Tags: mongodb, express, pug

I have a nested array in MongoDB database that I wish to display on the frontend using Jade and Express.

I am having some trouble displaying them:

This is the nested items I wish to display:

MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3343913d1e1323111fce6f"),
    "title" : "Projecten",
    "__v" : 0,
    "sub_items" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "item1"
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "item2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Mongoose Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  sub_items : {
    title: String
  }
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

I post the nested items with Express like this:

```
postController.updateSubItems = function(req,res,item) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var saveData = {
    title: req.body.sub_item
  };
  item.update({_id: id}, {$addToSet:{sub_items: saveData}}, (err, result) => {
  });
};
```

Display in jade like this:

```
each item in data
   p #{item.sub_items}
```

Eventually it comes out like this:

```
item1,item2
```

Like a string, though I want to display them like single items

Comment: 'sub_items' itself is an array it seems. Try looping through sub_items to print the titles.

Comment: Do you have an example how I can do this? Do I have to use Jade to loop over or Express?

Comment: I haven't used Jade, but I meant a loop within a loop

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, as per your sub_items object

```
  each item in [{sub_items:'sub_item_1'}]
   p=item.sub_items
```

Paste above code into this [editor](http://aramboyajyan.github.io/online-jade-template-editor/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a more elegant way to do this in Jade, but I just used the editor suggested by @iamwebkalakaar, tested the following snippet and it appears to print correctly:

`each item in [{"sub_items" : [{"title" : "item1"}, {"title" : "item2"}]}]
  each subitem in item.sub_items
   p=subitem.title`

New snippet

```
- var data = { "title" : "Projecten", "__v" : 0, "sub_items" : [ { "title" : "item1" }, { "title" : "item2" } ] };

 each subitem in data.sub_items
   p=subitem.title
```

Comment: No, I get the error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I tried the snippet above using the online editor and prints ok it seems.

Comment: That works indeed, but how can I get this done with the variable sub_items then?

Comment: @Larsmanson Updated the code - if you're 'data' will always be a single object, and the sub-items an array, then the code I just added should work. The data variable mimics what you get back from mongo.

Comment: When I do this, I get a very long output beginning with: 

true

function() { return this.$__.emitter[emitterFn].apply(this.$__.emitter, arguments); }

And this goes on for a long time